# Migrate ejabberd 1.3 to 20.4

Tags: windows

Due to a server change, I have to move the entire ejabber server 1.3 on a Windows Server 2008R2 (data + settings) to a new ejabber server 20.4 on a Windows Server 2019. So that all PSI data are retained, I wanted to ask if anyone can tell me how to do it.
Thanks in advance!
Best regards, Martin

Comment: According to the documentation `Only upgrade from version N to N+1 is documented and supported.`. sounds like fun.

Comment: I'd just set up the new server and skip the upgrade.